# Set active class in Vue router-link when optional param in parent route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an optional `lang` parameter at the beginning of all my routes paths like `/:lang?/foo`.

When I use the foo route in the `router-link` passing the `lang` param it matches that route and properly adds a `.router-link-active` class to the `<a/>`.

However in many places of my project I've passed no params to the `router-link` and in the global router navigation guard `beforeEach` I'm setting the `lang` param if no one is passed. In this case, `router-link` won't add the active class since it doesn't match the route because the missing param in the `to` prop.

How can I make the matching logic ignore that optional param for all routes so I have the `.router-link-active` and `.router-link-exact-active` classes added?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kq3jat1/1/) I played with where I want the first link to be red.

**Bellow are the relevant parts:**

```
  <router-link :to="{name: 'foo'}">/foo</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{name: 'foo', params: {lang: 'en'}}">/en/foo</router-link>
```

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/:lang?',
    component: {
      render(c) {
        return c('router-view');
      },
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'foo',
        path: 'foo',
        component: Foo
      }
    ]
  }
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.params.lang) {
    const route = { ...to };
    route.params = { ...route.params, lang: 'en'};
    next(route);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it by overriding the default vue router `resolve` method since it's also [used](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/components/link.js#L38) in the `router-link` for finding route matches accordingly to the `to` route.

So this is the code that solved my problem:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

class Router extends VueRouter {
  resolve(to, current, append) {
    const route = { ...to };
    route.params = { ...route.params, language: 'en' };
    return super.resolve(route, current, append);
  }
}

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by this way

```
<router-link :to="{ name : 'application', params : {sectorId: 1}}" class="menu-link" :class="[{'router-link-active active': $route.name === 'application'}]" >
```

that can work with indexOf as well

```
  <router-link :to="{ name : 'application', params : {sectorId: 1}}" class="menu-link" :class="[{'router-link-active active': $route.path.indexOf('application') > -1 }]" >
```

Comment: Probably the best solution here.
Solved my problem without overriding Route classes which is a complete overkill for a simple behavior...
looked like this in my case : 
:class = "{'router-link-exact-active': $route.name === RouteNames.MyRoute}"
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem and it looks like there is a better and much simpler solution.

Looks like you can make a part of the path optional and not just a parameter.
Take a look at the last route example [HERE](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js).

I just tried it and it works as expected.

This is actually being mentioned in the official docs but only as a "check here for more details" info which then brings you to the link I posted above.

Look under ["Advanced Matching Patterns"](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns).

---

**WARNING**

Only issue with this approach is that the URL doesn't get populated with the parameter.
e.g. if you create your route like this

```
{
    path: '(user/:userId/)?settings',
    name: 'UserSettings',
    component: UserSettingsComponent,
}
```

And then you try to route to it with

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'UserSettings', params: { userId: '123-456-789' } }">
    Go to user settings
</router-link>
```

Your URL will look like this

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/settings
```

This is a problem if you need to refresh or send a link to someone.